# What is difference between "have a look at" and "have one's look at"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In a opening of the news about several drugs for Alzheimer's disease, the news broadcaster said,
He(the reporter) has "our" look at the breakthroughs and what they could mean.

Why is not just simply "has a look" instead of "has our look"?
What implies "our" in that sentence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here, *our look at* means the program’s—or the network’s—story about. Similarly, if they said, “Tonight, we **look at** global warming,” it would mean that they were going to be presenting a story **about** global warming.

Calling it *our look* also suggests it is more complete than **a** look would be.

Answer (score 2):

"our look" could mean this news organization's interpretation of the subject matter. Or it could mean reporting that they've done themselves.

"a look" is more general -- it could be a story they're passing on from another news organization.